# Why ArrayList cannot store color in processing?

Tags: processing

```java
List<color> cr = new ArrayList<color>();
```

Why does the above code show me `Error on Dimensions`?

Comment: Without knowing what you want to do, or without having at least a snippet of runnable code, it's hard to help. The question becomes too broad to answer. It seems like ArrayList accepts objects only, and colour is not a valid one. I would suggest you create a class, with inside an object that has all the values you need to store in the ArrayList and use that instead as the ArrayList object!

Comment: I want to initial a set of custom objects' color. I must create a new class instead of using the already existing datatype(color) in processing?

Comment: Exactly. If you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532228/how-to-use-arraylist-in-processing) question, you'll see that a new class, with a new object is created to assign a different colour to every circle drawn on screen.
Once you've tried, if you're still struggling, edit the question to make it less broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)  instead of [color](https://processing.org/reference/color_.html):

```
import java.util.*;

List<Integer> cr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//populate list
for(int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++){
  cr.add(color(random(255),random(255),random(255)));
}

//retrieve values from list
for(int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++){
  fill(cr.get(i));
  rect(i % 10 * 10, i / 10 * 10,10,10);
}
```

Why ?

> ArrayList can only reference types, not primitives. Integer is a class, not a primitive.

More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349011/why-i-cant-have-int-in-the-type-of-arraylist)

In this case the [color datatype](https://processing.org/reference/color_datatype.html) is a primitive.